# Using the Laplace transform of an integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I want to find the function $x(t)$ which unilatteral Laplace transform is:

$$\mathcal X(p) = \frac{a}{p(p+b)} \tag 1$$

I know that:
$$\mathcal L_u^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{p+a}\right) = e^{-at}\nu(t)\tag 2$$

And:

$$\mathcal L_u\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = p\mathcal X(p) \tag 3$$

So my idea is to "reverse" $(3)$ and to suppose the "$1/p$" means an integral:

$$x(t) = a\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-bu}\nu(t) \ du \tag 4$$

Is this correct and thorough or is their a problem ?

Comment: Use partial fraction decomposition and apply the inverse Laplace transform on the terms individually.

Comment: That was the idea given by my book (that and the residue theorem) but I just wondered if my reasonment was abusive or acceptable

Comment: Take the Laplace transform of $x(t)$ and check whether you get back $\mathcal{X}(p)$.

Comment: @KBS It gives back $\mathcal X$, but it doens't prove that my reasonment is acceptable, even if it is correct in the present exercice

Comment: Your idea is based on the assumption that $p$ is the same as the differential operator, and they are certainly similar but not the same...

Comment: Ok, I'll use the partial fraction décomposition then instead. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be
$$
X(p)=\frac{a}{p(p+b)}=\frac{F(p)}{p}\Longrightarrow x(t)=\int_0^tf(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau
$$
and
$$
f(t)=\mathcal L^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{p+b}\right)=a\,\mathrm e^{-bt}u(t)
$$
where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. So we have
$$
x(t)=\int_0^tf(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau=a\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-b\tau}u(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau=a\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-b\tau}\,\mathrm d\tau=\frac{a}{b}\left(1- e^{-bt}\right)u(t)
$$

The same result with partial fraction décomposition
$$
X(p)=\frac{a}{p(p+b)}=\frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p+b}\right)\Longrightarrow x(t)=\frac{a}{b}\left(1- e^{-bt}\right)u(t)
$$